# Angular get value from control in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have a button which switches between map view and list view

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-segment #viewController (ionChange)="changeViewState($event)">
      <ion-segment-button value="map">
        <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="list">
        <ion-label>List</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  <app-list-base *ngIf="viewValue == 'list'" [config]="config" [template]="itemTemplate"></app-list-base>
  <app-map *ngIf="viewValue == 'map'" [config]="config"></app-map>
</ion-content>
```

Currently I'm using the ionChange event to set the viewValue.  However seeing as I just need the raw value from the control I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this in the html only

e.g

```
<app-list-base *ngIf="#viewController.val == 'list'" [config]="config" [template]="itemTemplate"></app-list-base>
```

How can I obtain the viewController value though html?

Comment: Maybe `*ngIf="viewController.value === 'list'"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is `*ngIf="viewController.value"` without `#` but the Angular way is use [(ngModel)] -or even ReactiveForms-

```
<ion-segmen [(ngModel)]="myvariable">
...
<ion-segmen>
<app-list-base *ngIf="myvariable">
```

where "myvariable" is a variable in your .ts

NOTE:Currently, Ionic Framework has official integration with Angular, so, you can use all you know about Angular. Well Ionic has certains characteristics, but the idea model-view is fulfilled

NOTE2: Really I think all the examples in the docs, need a revisited